# Is it possible to partitioning a psql table along columns?

Tags: postgresql, citus

At the moment I have several tables with around 4000 columns in sum and approx. 1 Mio. rows each with the same index column.

I have build partitioning manually to split these columns into batches of ~1500 (bc. psql max. amount of columns is 1600).

1. Question: Is there a managed and more efficient way similar to partitioning on a range of a specific column?
2. Question: Do you think it is suitable way to use citus 10 `COLUMNAR` support and remove the primary key on the index?

Comment: If you need that many columns that it's highly likely that your data model is wrong.

Comment: We have evaluated several kind of table structures to store a 4D dataset and using columns for 2D (variable and forecast horizon) and rows for the other 2D (indices derived from lat and lon coordinates) was the fastest way.

Comment: if you are storing arrays, then why not use two columns that are defined as arrays? Or use `point` or other geometry types?

Comment: We will test partitioning along the forcast horizon axes. Forecast horizons having 93 steps. So we reduce the amount of columns to 39. Do you recommend to use 93 partitions or larger batches?  Point geometry uses 8 times more space than a smallint. And the disadvantage of arrays is that the whole array has to be loaded to access an index that increases the query time.

Comment: "*Forecast horizons having 93 steps*" then you should have 93 _rows_ not columns

Comment: 93 * (657*1095) = 66905595 is the exact amount of rows we have. And this for 39 variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230405/discussion-between-dl-meteo-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 2):

Citus 10 COLUMNAR storage seems like a good candidate for your use-case. It uses *Projection Pushdown*, meaning that if the queries you usually run are targeting a few columns, they will skip over the columns they don’t need.

Regarding your second question, there is some sort of “indexing” in Columnar. Queries use *Chunk Group Filtering*, which allows them to skip over chunk groups of data for certain filters in the columns. Let me copy & paste the relevant section from a blog post about Citus columnar:

> Chunk Group Filtering allows queries to skip over Chunk Groups of data
> if the metadata indicates that none of the data in the chunk group
> will match the predicate. In other words, for certain kinds of queries
> and data sets, it can skip past a lot of the data quickly, without
> even decompressing it!

Comment: Do I have to define a column for the orientation of the chunks or is it made automatically?

Comment: Chunks are defined automatically for every column of the table.